# Removing markers from google maps xml

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

I am trying to display markers on Google Maps which refresh periodically.

I found this piece of code which will add them to the map but I need to know **how to delete them every refresh** so that it stops displaying on the map when they are no longer in the xml file.

```
< script >
var map = null;

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3478, -6.2597) //center over dublin
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
loadXMLFile();
}

function loadXMLFile() {
var filename = 'data.xml';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: filename,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXML,
    error: onXMLLoadFailed
});

function onXMLLoadFailed() {
    alert("An Error has occurred.");
}

function parseXML(xml) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    $(xml).find("marker").each(function() {
        //Read the name, address, latitude and longitude for each Marker
        var nme = $(this).find('name').text();
        var address = $(this).find('address').text();
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
        var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
        bounds.extend(markerCoords);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerCoords,
            map: map
        });
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 
< /script>
```

This works great when new markers are added by calling the function loadXMLFile() but if they are removed then they stay on the map. I think I need to remove them  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove but I don't know how to apply this.

This has been driving me nuts for days. Can anyone help me out?

EDIT:

My full code is not rendering the map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
#map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
var map;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.76522, 18.35002)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('add-markers'), 'click', addMarkers);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('remove-markers'), 'click', removeMarkers);
}

function addMarkers() {

    var coords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002),
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.45522, 18.12002),
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.86522, 18.35002),
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.77522, 18.88002),
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.36344, 18.36346),
    new google.maps.LatLng(59.56562, 18.33002)];

    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: coords[i]
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    }
}

function removeMarkers() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

initialize();

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
<button id="add-markers">Add markers</button>
<button id="remove-markers">Remove markers</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create an array to hold your markers

```
var markers = [];
```

2) Push each marker to the array when you add them to the map

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerCoords,
    map: map
});

markers.push(marker);
```

3) When you need to remove them, iterate through your array and call `setMap(null)` on each marker

```
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {

    markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Hope this helps.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/b5r4nm3s/)</kbd>

**Edit**:

Here is your code updated with my modifications. I guess you *periodically* call the `loadXMLFile()` function (?).

```
var map = null;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3478, -6.2597) //center over dublin
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    loadXMLFile();
}

function loadXMLFile() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    var filename = 'data.xml';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: filename,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXML,
        error: onXMLLoadFailed
    });

    function onXMLLoadFailed() {
        alert("An Error has occurred.");
    }

    function parseXML(xml) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function () {
            //Read the name, address, latitude and longitude for each Marker
            var nme = $(this).find('name').text();
            var address = $(this).find('address').text();
            var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
            var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
            bounds.extend(markerCoords);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerCoords,
                map: map
            });

            markers.push(marker);
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: So I can see that this is working on jsfiddle, but when I try to put it into the page it won't render the map. I am replacing the javascript from the basic example on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple with the script provided but no joy. Any ideas?

Comment: Edit your question with what you did (add the code).

Comment: edited. I am waiting for someone to point out my silly rookie error :)

Comment: Oh well I am a bit lost. You just basically copied my code. This was just an example. You should adapt it to yours. To relevant parts are in my answer (points 1, 2, 3). Let me add your code to my answer with the modifications.

Comment: Perhaps a [better example](http://jsfiddle.net/b5r4nm3s/3/), calls addMarkers every 5 seconds, creating 10 random markers every time, deletes them before creating the new ones.

Comment: thank you guys. your help has been a lifesaver for me.